# Is any automatic way to avoid Web API EF WebApi Self referencing loop issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Is any automatic way to avoid Self referencing loop issue in EF Web API, and
i like to know effect of LazyLoadingEnabled = false on  Web API application performance

I am using EF Database first with ASP.Net 4.5 Web API

But when try to get data from web API getting error

> Error Self referencing loop detected for type System.data.entity
>   occurs

then i set

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

it will fix the error but it is returning lot of data like this:

```
[
employee1 : {
    name: "name",
    department : {
        name: "departmentName",
        employees : [
            employee1 : {
                name: "name",
                department : {
                    name: "departmentName",
                    employees : [
                        employee1 : {
                            name: "name",
                            department : {
                                and again and again....
                            }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then I disabled LazyLoading in datacontext

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Now only returing needed data but i like to know is any trade of for this approach ?

the Datacontext is in separate class library and and used by other projects, is it effect application profomence ?

It is not a duplicate of [exclude-reverse-navigation in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273760/can-you-exclude-reverse-navigation-properties-in-ef-when-eager-loading) i am looking for some setting change or Fix (i am ok to change TT generator file ,if it fix the issue) more than one person is working on project and i cannot force others to write code in particular way.

Comment: This is the fault in your database, there can be cyclic references which dbms is baring but not entity framework. You can check you entities which contain foreign key references

Comment: @Lali  i don't think so , i try creating Web API for Microsoft Northwind database and got the same error